# convert to LLVM IR: how to create virtual register instead of allocate a stack variable?

Tags: llvm

I am working on converting another IR to llvm IR.

My IR is like this:

```
a = 1;
b = a;
a = a + 1;
```

For now, I am using alloca to create variable in my IR (Here for "a" and "b").

However, alloca probably is too heavy, it will introduce lots of load store instructions. This will be a problem if the function is huge. Actually, for my case, most of the variables are register-width. So I just want them be a virtual register with name.

Anybody know how to create a virtual register(variable) instead of memory variable?

I mean how to avoid using "alloca"?

Comment: AFAIK, you shouldn't care about this. Just use allocas and codegen/optimizer will do the job for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to. Generating SSA code is a quite hard problem, so it's solved once for all frontends in LLVM passes. You are *supposed to* use `alloca` and load/store, and then run the `mem2reg` pass to convert those into SSA variables. Clang also does this (stick your example code in a C function, and [compile it](http://llvm.org/demo) with no optimizations).